# how to display large amounts of data while keeping the app responsive

Tags: android, user-interface

In my Android app, I've got a background thread that downloads a lot of data from the network. The thread then parses the data into a form ready for display. Eventually, the thread needs to display this data - i.e. modify a lot of UI elements. The displaying can be only done from the UI thread. If I try to display everything in one go, on my phone it takes about 3 seconds, during which the app appears frozen.

So I've split the displaying into several chunks and wait in between like so:

```
void backroudThreadDownloadData()
  {
  downloadDataFromInternet();
  parseData();
  int N = splitIntoChunksForDisplaying();

  for(int chunk=0; chunk<N; chunk++)
    {
    final int CHUNK = chunk;

    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
      {
      public void run()
        {
        displayChunk(CHUNK);
        }
      });

    try
      {
      Thread.sleep(200);
      }
    catch( InterruptedException ie)
      { }
    }
  }
```

This more or less works; the data gets displayed and the app remains mostly responsive during that time. However, it still feels like a hack - especially since I don't really know how long to sleep between the next invocations of the 'displayChunk()' thing.

Any better suggestions how to display large amounts of data while keeping the app responsive?

Answer (score 1):

For displaying large amounts of data you should consider using `PagedList` and displaying it in a `RecyclerView` using a `PagedListAdapter`.

You can only be pointed in the right direction as it won't be possible to create the whole implementation of this solution right here.

Following are some useful links in this regard:

[Paging Library Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging)

[PagedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList)

[PagedListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedListAdapter.html?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is Tiled Rendering. 
basically display what you are capable to compute. then change it at users will.

think that as displaying huge image files (50kx50k jpeg file). 
are start you get relatively low res thumbnail of image beacuse phone image cant show that big file (2kx1k image) 
then you will get details at zoom.

to fully implement this process you would be needing a manager(viewer) and a renderer(adapter).

another example is viewing infinite lists with recycle view

as a manager recycleview is a good example. we use that with writing a renderer(adapter) class